# Can mysql trigger update a cell?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've got a mysql table 'market' with columns `open_time (datetime)`, `session_num (int)`, `duration (int)`, `close_time (datetime)`.

How can I make a trigger to automatically calculate the default value for `close_time` if someone insert [open_time, session_num, duration]?

I want `close_time = open_time + session_num * duration`?

Can trigger do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can create trigger for insert, something like this:

```
delimiter ;;
create trigger insertTriggerTest
before insert on sampletable
for each row
begin
    set new.close_time = new.open_time + new.session_num * new.duration;
end;;
delimiter ;
```

NOTE - new.session_num * new.duration should be in seconds

Answer (score 0):

Definetely yes, you just need to update the values based on your inserted row.

Here's [how you can do this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).